# lots of moisture on the lid of the fermenter

Tags: beer, cider, fermenter

I have had a lot of condensation or moisture on the lid of the fermenter when I open it during/at the end of primary fermentation. Is this normal?

I am very thorough with my cleaning and sterilizing and always have an appropriate airlock in place but am wondering if there is any way that this will affect my brew?

During the day at the moment the house is around 18-22 degrees C. I am not sure what the temperatures are inside the house during the night.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Out of my 12-13 brews I have almost always had condensation on the inside of the lid of the fermentation bucket.

I have had a thermometer inside the liquid during fermentation, and one on the outside and it does differ quite a bit. Basically the fermentation causes heat => condensation.

Totally normal!

Comment: Yes - totally normal. During active fermentation lid is colder than the beer causing some water vapor to condense.

Comment: Is there any way that the condensation could affect the brew or contaminate it? I have had a cider sitting in its fermenter for almost 2 months and would hate to think how much condensation has been dripping into the brew.

Comment: Well, if you think about it, it is a closed system (assuming that your airlock is working like it should). This means that all that condensation is actually just water coming out of your brew due to the heat difference of the liquid and it's surrounding. The only thing that might have an effect was if you were to remove all of the condensation your might make your beer stronger, since you are in fact removing water. (Wouldn't really be a noticeable amount...)